# How to make sgen.exe keep the version of the assembly?

Tags: .net, serialization, version, sgen

I want to create a serialization assembly for my assembly.  `sgen` does it fine, but I can't figure out how to get it to assign the serialization assembly the same version as the source assembly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sgen` seem to take source assembly version by default, it is quite reasonable.

Here is how I run it, there is nothing special:

> "...PathToSDK...\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   SDK\sgen.exe" /force
>   /assembly:"$(TargetPath)"
>   /compiler:"\"/keyfile:$(ProjectDir)..\key.snk"\"
>   /compiler:/delaysign-

/force -- to overwrite existing serializer assemblies

/assembly -- path to the assembly, I run it in the post-build event in the VS project settings, so I use the `$(TargetPath)` variable

/compiler: ... -- csc options, I use them to sign serializer assemblies with the key